# How to have No primary Key Entity using ManyToOne Relation to fetch data from mysql database

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am having problem with fetching data from a table which doesn't contain any primary key (a Weak Entity). I have two tables - `Data` and `Prescription`. In `Prescription` there is a primary key - `token_id` and `Data` contains more than 1 row containing different types of information about a single `token_id`. How I can do that?
I can't add any primary key to the table. The table is provided to me so I cannot change that.

I tried and followed some tutorials in YouTube but that didn't worked. I also checked some answers in stackoverflow but that didn't seem to go with my api structure. I am completely stuck. I tried to use `@MantToOne` as shown in the tutorial and then use a repository for a function but that doesn't seem to work.

I have two model classes - 
Data.java

```
@Repository
@Entity
@Table(name="data")

public class Data {


    @Column(name="ticket_no")
    private String ticket_no;

    @Column(name="type")    
    String type;    

    @Column(name="unit")
    private String unit;

    @Column(name="value")
    private float value;

    @ManyToOne
    private Prescription pres;
    //getters and setters

}
```

Prescription.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="prescriptions")
public class Prescription {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ticket_no")
    private String ticket_no;

    @Column(name="description")    
    String description; 

    @Column(name="download_link")
    private String download_link;

    //getters and setters
```

Two Repositories: DataRepository.java

```
public interface DataRepository extends JpaRepository<Data, String> {

 public List<Data> findByPrescriptionTicket_no(String token);

}
```

PrescriptionRepository.java

```
public interface PrescriptionRepository extends JpaRepository<Prescription, String> {   
}
```

Two Dao Classes : DataDao.java

```
@Service
public class DataDao {


    @Autowired
    DataRepository datarepo;

    public List<Data> findOne(String token) {
        List<Data> meddat=new ArrayList<>();
        datarepo.findByPrescriptionTicket_no(token).forEach(meddat::add);
        return meddat;
    }
}
```

PrescriptionDao.java

```
@Service
public class PrescriptionDao {


    @Autowired
    PrescriptionRepository presrepo;

    public Prescription findOne(String token) {
        return presrepo.findOne(token);
    }
}
```

The Controller Class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/users")
public class MainController {


    @Autowired
    DataDao datadao;

    @Autowired
    PrescriptionDao presdao;

    @Autowired
    ProcessData pd;

     @GetMapping("/persons")
     public String loadPersons(@RequestParam("access_token") String access_token) throws  ParseException{
        String decode_token = pd.testDecodeJWT(access_token);
        String token = pd.jsondata(decode_token);
        String pres=presdao.findOne(token).toString();
        List<Data> med= datadao.findOne(token);
        String tot_data= "{"+"\"medical_data\":"+med+","+"\"hb_prescription\":"+pres+"}";
        return tot_data;


     }

}
```

I actually converted the whole program from a simple fetching of data from two tables to this one so there can be more than one error. I am new to this concept but I have to do this for the project submission. 
If the result is in Data List than it would be great.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: On the entity Data, is there any field that it is unique? Or combination of fields? What happen is: it is mandatory the Entity to have an ID not the table itself.

Comment: @Brother The main problem was to get data from such a table . There is a token to be sent and that contains only the ticket_no . Therefore there was no way to make candidate keys because I wouldn't know anything other than the ticket no. Later I found that there is another key which can make a candidate key and then  I solved it using Simon Martinelli way.

Comment: Nice @Chaos, I imagine, we talked in his comments and he gave an awesome answer that is why I didn't post anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have Entities without primary key:

From the Spec:

> 2.4 Primary Keys and Entity Identity
>
> Every entity must have a primary key.
>
> The primary key must be defined
> on the entity class that is the root of the entity hierarchy or on a
> mapped superclass that is a (direct or indirect) superclass of all
> entity classes in the entity hierarchy. The primary key must be
> defined exactly once in an entity hierarchy.

Source: https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf?AuthParam=1561040540_b447233fdfd994fdb2338dd9407c4977

So you must create a primary key of the fields of data.

If they are unique in combination you could create a composite key like this:

```
public class DataKey implements Serializable  {

    @Id
    private String ticket_no;

    @Id
    String type;    

    @Id
    private String unit;

    @Id
    private float value;

    // getters, setters, equals and hashCode implementations
}

@Entity
@Table(name="data")
@IdClass(DataKey.class)
public class Data {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ticket_no")
    private String ticket_no;

    @Id
    @Column(name="type")    
    String type;    

    @Id
    @Column(name="unit")
    private String unit;

    @Id
    @Column(name="value")
    private float value;

    @ManyToOne
    private Prescription pres;

    //getters and setters

}
```

Comment: Cool Simon, but he doesnt know what to do with it. You should suggest him instead of only answering this, to create a Composed Id / EmbeddedId with all field that identify the row as unique.

Comment: @Brother I'm sorry for being rude. I added and example with a composite key to my answer.

Comment: Oh no @Simon. Just to help him, As I saw you are experienced, I knew you could give a direction =) .. perfect answer!

Comment: @Brother You know sometimes it's exhausting to answer the same questions over and over again. Mostly questions that could be answered by reading the docs, a book or tutorial or nowadays a YouTube video..